# How to configure two monitors on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, monitor, external-monitor

I'm a front-end developer and I work with a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. Recently, I bought a Full HD monitor in order to better test my applications.

But the main thing I want to do, I hadn't achieved yet, that is write code in my laptop and visualize the result at the same time in my monitor.

In other words... I would have Sublime Text/Terminal opened in the laptop and the browser opened in the monitor.

How can I achieve it? Any help is welcome.

Comment: This article is pretty simple, check this out. [Ubuntu Tips: How To Setup Dual Monitor](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/08/ubuntu-tips-how-to-setup-dual-monitor)

Comment: @MohammedOmer, do you know what Ubuntu version exampled in your link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this quite simply from in the settings

This guide covers it quite well:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html **(Latest Ubuntu Version)**

As an overview you would go to System Settings, then Screen Display where you can turn the monitor on and off. Make sure to not have ticked "Mirror Display"

Hope that helps

**Edit: For Ubuntu 16.04 - Copied from the docs (no longer available):**

To set up an external monitor with your laptop, connect the monitor to your laptop. If your system doesn't recognise it immediately, or you would like to adjust the settings:

1. Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System
   Settings.
2. Open Screen Display.
3. Click on the image of the monitor you would like to activate or deactivate, then switch it ON/OFF.
4. By default, the Launcher only shows on the primary monitor. To change which monitor is "primary", change the monitor in the Launcher Placement drop-down box. You could also drag the Launcher in the preview to the monitor you want to set as the "primary" monitor.
5. If you want the Launcher to show on all monitors, change Launcher Placement to All Displays.
6. To change the "position" of a monitor, click on it and drag it to the desired position.
7. If you would like both monitors to display the same content, check the Mirror displays box.
8. When you are happy with your settings, click Apply and then click Keep This Configuration.
9. To close the Displays click on the x in the top corner.

Comment: This page goes to 19.04.  No way to view older versions of Ubuntu (such as 16.04).

Comment: The overview says what to do, but if more detail is needed this guide is still available from this link https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html

Comment: @MarkAroni would you update your link? Thanks.

Comment: The question was asked relating to 16.04 which is no longer available. However the steps have been copied into the answer. The first link in my answer gives all details for the latest version of Ubuntu. For the current latest LTS version (20.04) please use this link https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html